# What are the current payUMoney test credentials

Tags: payment-gateway, payumoney

I'm working with PayUMoney Payment integration PHP APIs, I want the current test credentials I have the old test environment credentials as fallows:

```
Test Card Name: any name
Test Card Number: 5123456789012346
Test CVV: 123
Test Expiry: May 2017
```

But this is not working out to test the success case (as the card expiry date is already expired)

I want the current Test credentials

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: Actually I have change the payment gateway upon my client's request, so I didn't get a change to verify your answer. I appreciate your help :).. hope next time when I use PayUmoney it will surely help me :)

Answer (score 10):

Use below credentials for test server:
Mine is working fine-

```
Card Type: Visa
Card: 4012 0010 3714 1112
CVV: 123
Name: Test
Expiry: 05/20
OTP:123456

Card Type: Master    
Card: 5123 4567 8901 2346
CVV: 123
Name: Test
Expiry: 05/20
OTP:123456
```

[image]

Comment: People who land on this page looking for Simulator OTP, it is 123456

Answer (score 4):

From their [documentation](https://help.payu.co.za/display/developers/Test+Credentials):

> For any of the cards below you can use:
>   01/2020 as expiry date
>   and
>   123 as CVV
>
> 4000015372250142
>   4000019562093601
>   4000019542438801
>   4000029520272445

Comment: Thumbs up for your kind help :)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
Card Type: Visa

Card Name: Test

Card Number: 4012001037141112

Expiry Date : 05/20

CVV : 123

Card Type: Master

Card Name: Test

Card Number: 5123456789012346

Expiry Date : 05/20

CVV : 123
```

Answer (score 0):

It failed each time I tried to make a payment in test environment using above cards. I went to integration details section from the very first drop down in the right , and there I got the test card detail , one visa and a master card. That gave me success.

Comment: You should provide the test credentials here so others can easily find it

Answer (score 0):

Pay U Test Credit Card Details:

```
Credit Card #: 4012001037141112
Expiry Month/Year: 05/20
CVV Code: 123
Name: Any name
```

Comment: You can also use this Credit Card #: 5123456789012346

Answer (score 0):

***As tested on 28/12/2021***

```
Card Type: Visa

Card Number: 4012-0010-3714-1112

Card Name: Test

CVV : 123

Expiry Date : 05/30

OTP: 123456
```

**Keep in mind you can give any future Expiration date of your choice.**